# how to get the object from an array element

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to get the object value from an array of objects

```
public getDocuments(rowData : any ) {
    this.docsList =[];
    const docsCodesSplited = rowData.docsCodes.toString().split(',');
    docsCodesSplited .forEach(element => this.docsList.push(this.allDocuments.filter(doc=> doc.documentCode === element )));
    console.info("test  this.docsList " + this.docsList .length);
    return this.docsList ;
}
```

the size of docsList is always >0

docsList is an array of objects and each object has documentName, documentId and documentCode

in the html

```
                                        <p-dropdown
                                        [options]="getDocuments(rowData)"
                                        [required]="true"
                                        optionLabel="documentName"
                                    >
                                    </p-dropdown>
```

any help please, what do i need to change to get the list of the required documents ?

Comment: With angular 17 you can follow [this guide](https://angular.io/api/core/for)

Comment: `this.docsList[0].documentName` as @DucHo said you can run for loop in your HTML now...

Comment: you need a `for` loop. From Angular 17, you can use this syntax `@for(let document of getDocuments(data); track document) { <p-dropdown [optionLabel]="document.label".../> }`. before Angular 17, you would use this syntax : `<p-dropdown *ngFor="let document of getDocuments(data)"`

Comment: Can you provide more info on what is not working? The dropdown not showing the options? I don't see why you need to call the function from HTML, you can just place the `getDocuments(rowData)` to assign value to `docsList` in `ngOnInit`, then in HTML `<p-dropdown [options]="docsList" ...>`.